# .htaccess in upper directories being ignored

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in /var/www/html/htc directory with specific rules to bookmatic.net and another .htaccess file with general rules to all domains in /var/www/html

When accesing bookmatic.net, the .htaccess file in /htc is running good, but the one in /html is being ignored. Can anyone help?

bookmatic.net specs in httpd.conf are like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bookmatic.net
    ServerAlias *.bookmatic.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/htc
    AllowEncodedSlashes On

    <Directory /var/www/html/htc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        LimitRequestBody 25000000
        LimitXMLRequestBody 25000000
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` files in your question. (From comments below it sounds like you may have a conflict or directives that are incompatible in the context they are being used?) Also, why are you enabling the `RewriteEngine` in the vHost, you don't appear to have any mod_rewrite directives here? And why are you enabling `MultiViews`?

Answer (score 2):

`AllowOverride All` is the directive that tells Apache to look in `.htaccess` files for more configuration.

That vhost tells Apache to look for `.htaccess` files in `/var/www/html/htc` and deeper so it doesn't cover the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html`.

One way to solve this would be to create another block like this (possibly in `httpd.conf` rather than this vhost if that makes more sense):

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: I actually tryed it before posting the question; tryed once again (I'm keeping all blokc in this vhost for tests not to mess with working domains):  
  
`ServerName bookmatic.net  
ServerAlias *.bookmatic.net  
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/htc
AllowEncodedSlashes On  
  
<Directory /var/www/html/htc>  
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
AllowOverride All  
Require all granted  
LimitRequestBody 25000000  
LimitXMLRequestBody 25000000  
</Directory>  
  
<Directory /var/www/html>  
    AllowOverride All  
</Directory>`  
  
RESULT = Error 500

Comment: That sounds like it worked but there's something in the other `.htaccess` file that is causing the 500 response. There will likely be something in your error logs about it or you could find the offending line by commenting them out one by one.

Comment: I don't believe this would be the error 500 cause, as the other htacces is serving all other domains in my server and they're all working properly. Actually, if I remove `/htc`in `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/htc`and `<Directory /var/www/html/htc>`, all works well too

Comment: @DiegoFlores You should edit your question to include this additional information (avoid including code dumps in unformatted _comments_). Your error log will have more details regarding the 500 response.

Answer (score 2):

You have `AllowOverride All` for `<Directory /var/www/html/htc>`. I suppose it's not allowed in `/var/www/html`. You could try:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: I actually tryed it before posting but tryed once again (I'm keeping all block in this vhost for tests not mess working domains) [sorry I cant get comments to format code]:  
  
`ServerName bookmatic.net  
ServerAlias *.bookmatic.net  
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/htc
AllowEncodedSlashes On  
  
<Directory /var/www/html/htc>  
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
AllowOverride All  
Require all granted  
LimitRequestBody 25000000  
LimitXMLRequestBody 25000000  
</Directory>  
  
<Directory /var/www/html>  
    AllowOverride All  
</Directory>`  
  
RESULT = Error 500